# How can I add an extra WooCommerce hook

Tags: functions, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

In the standard WooCommerce template file `content-single-product.php` there is a set of hooks that control the way the page lays out in a series of blocks which are called by a series of hooks eg `'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary'`. If you are familiar with WooCommerce you will know what I mean.

There are three of these

- `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary`
- `woocommerce_single_product_summary`
- `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary`

For my layout I need to add a fourth along the lines of `'woocommerce_before_single_product_intro'`

I understand that I can move content around, such as moving the title to before the image. That seems to work fine, but I can't work out how to add a new hook.

I have tried adding `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_intro', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );` to my functions file but it didn't work and I am guessing I have missed something rather important from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a hook by calling [do_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/), then referring to the hook in your `functions.php` with [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

For example, in the theme, *where you want the action to occur*:

```
do_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_intro');
```

Then in `functions.php`

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_intro','your_function',[...]);
```

For the sake of maintainability, I'd choose a naming convention that doesn't confuse your hooks with WooCommerce's.

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat, and a good point about the naming convention, have taken that on board.